# HttpPostedFileBase nulo depois de recarregar a pagina, (upload de imagem)

Tags: c#, .net, razor

Existe algum modo de eu não perder os dados do `HttpPostedFileBase`? minha action faz uma checagem, e em caso de falha a pagina recarrega com a imagem no formulario e tenho que fazer a chamada denovo, então `HttpPostedFileBase` vai nulo,a menos que eu escolha a imagem denovo.

```
@{
Dictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
htmlAttributes.Add("id", "delivery-form");
htmlAttributes.Add("class", "middle-forms");
htmlAttributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
}

@using (Html.BeginForm(actionName, "DeliveryService", ViewBag.Routes as RouteValueDictionary, FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes @*new { @id = "delivery-form", @class = "middle-forms" }*@))
{
```

Primera chamada:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segunda Chamada:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**UPDATE**

Uma solução que arrumei foi usar uma `Session` para salvar os dados do `HttpPostedFileBase`, ficando assim:

```
Session["ImportFile"] = ImportFile;
```

Comment: Acredito que não exista, pois se fosse possível atribuir um valor a um `input` do tipo `file` vindo do servidor teríamos uma falha grave de segurança do navegador.

Comment: Talvez você possa fazer uma validação parcial antes de postar a imagem?

Comment: Você poderia fazer a validação no client...

Comment: Já tinhamos conversado antes aqui no projeto sobre essa validação, o melhor caminho vai ser mudar mesmo.

Comment: de repente salvar o item no localstorage e reenviar no submit

Comment: estou tentando a dica do @RafaelLarrosa do localStorage, estou tentando mandar ele no submit agora.

Answer (score -1):

Eu faço assim, crio uma tabela que salva informações da imagem, tais como, caminho, nome, extensão, etc... sendo assim, você pode fazer o upload via ajax, usando angum plugin, e retornar o id dela, assim no submit você envia esse id junto com o model, e trata no backend

Comment: acho que essa não é uma boa solução porque estou escolhendo a imagem para ser salva junto com os dados do formulário, alem do fato de ter que criar uma tabela para salvar os dados após isso salvar a imagem antes do formulário. Eu uso o caminho da imagem para carregar ela após ser salva, mas nesse momento ainda não foi salva.